# Property about odd function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

Let $y: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an odd and continuous function and $T>0$. Suppose that there exists $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that
$$
\int_0^T \varphi(x)\; dx=0 \tag{1}
$$
and, for some constant $\gamma>0$,
$$
y(x+T)=y(x)+\gamma\varphi(x), \; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{2}
$$
**Question.** Is it true that
$$
\int_0^T y(x) \; dx =0? \tag{*}
$$

I thought of the following: integrating $(2)$ over $[0,T]$ and using $(1)$ we obtain
$$
\int_0^T y(x+L) \; dx = \int_T^{2T} y(u) \; dx. \tag{3}
$$

Now, I know that, since $y$ is odd then holds $$\int_{-T}^T y(x)\; dx=0. \tag{4}$$

Can I use $(4)$ in order to prove $(*)$? If so, how can I use it?

Comment: The result does not follow, but it would if $\varphi$ satisfied $\int_{-T}^0 \varphi(x) \;\text{d}x = 0$ instead.

Comment: @dxiv Why is true? If $\varphi$ is periodic (with period $T>0$) and $(1)$ holds, then $\int_{-T}^0 \varphi(x) \; dx=0$?

Comment: The question doesn't mention $\varphi$ being periodic. Without periodicity, all you can say is that $\int_0^T y(x) \mathbb dx = \int_{-T}^0 y(x+T) \,\mathbb dx = \int_{-T}^0 y(x) \,\mathbb dx + \lambda \int_{-T}^0 \varphi(x) \,\mathbb dx$. If the latter term is $0$ then $\int_0^T y(x) \,\mathbb dx = \int_{-T}^0 y(x) \,\mathbb dx$, but on the other hand $\int_0^T y(x) \,\mathbb dx = -\int_{-T}^0 y(x) \,\mathbb dx$ because $y$ is odd, so in the end $\int_0^T y(x) \,\mathbb dx = 0$.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I agree. I means that if $\varphi$ be periodic is a sufficient condition in order that $\int_{-T}^0 \varphi(x) \; dx=0$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $y = \sin(x)$ and $T = \frac{\pi}{2}$. We have $y(x + T) = \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(x)$. Then define $\phi(x) = \cos(x) - \sin(x)$, $\gamma = 1$. Then we have $y(x + T) = y(x) + \gamma \phi(x)$. And note that $y$ is odd.

Furthermore, note that $\int\limits_0^T \phi(x) dx = 0$. But $\int\limits_0^T y(x) dx = 1$.

So your claim is not true.